# Opening a video through PHP's shell_exec fails on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, bash, video, php, exec

I'm hosting a local web application on my computer (Mac OS X) which contains a button to open a video with QuickTime. On button click an AJAX request is made to a PHP script with the following content:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/open $videoFile"; // For example: $videoFile = '/Users/.../Downloads/abc.mp4'
$code = "Performing cmd: $cmd";
shell_exec($cmd);
echo '{code: "$code"}'; // JSON debug output
```

Depending on the button multiple videos can be opened. The problem is, that it does not always works:

- videos I opened manually or with the same command in the Terminal app can be opened with no problems by the PHP script
- unopened videos (before) do not open, instead the QuickTime icon jumps in the dock but no window is shown. Then I paste the exact same command into the Terminal app and QT opens. If I quit QT and try the script again it works without any problem (all video files are checked before hand if they physically exists; `exec(...)` does not work either)